# d3.js Specify text for x-axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, axis-labels

My x-axis currently has numbered ticks. I want the ticks to be replaced with data from my object (specifically the *keyword* value). How would I accomplish this?

[**I have a working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/enigmarm/juY5E/6/)

```
var dataset = [
            {"keyword": "payday loans", "global": 1400000, "local": 673000, "cpc": "14.11"},
            {"keyword": "title loans", "global": 165000, "local": 160000, "cpc": "12.53" },
            {"keyword": "personal loans", "global": 550000, "local": 301000, "cpc": "6.14"},
            {"keyword": "online personal loans", "global": 15400, "local": 12900, "cpc": "5.84"},
            {"keyword": "online title loans", "global": 111600, "local": 11500, "cpc": "11.74"}
        ];

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .orient("bottom");
// xAxis
svg.append("g") // Add the X Axis
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h) + ")")
    .call(xAxis);
//xAxis Label
svg.append("text") 
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w / 2) + " ," + (h + margin.bottom - 5) +")")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("Keyword");
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is to set the `tickFormat` function for your axis:

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .tickFormat(function(d) { return dataset[d].keyword; })
    .orient("bottom");
```

You might have to tweak the width a bit to fit the labels (or [rotate them](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/how-to-rotate-text-labels-for-x-axis-of.html)).

The "proper" way to do this would be to specify the domain values for you `xScale` as the keywords instead of the array indices. Then you would have to change all the other code that uses `xScale` as well though.

Comment: Very nice. I had tried something similar. But it broke the axis all together. But it works now! Thank you. Then I added some styling to rotate the text to prevent it from overlapping.

Answer (score 3):

This is called an ordinal axis, check out [the example from the creator](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3259783)